# bind list item's property to any parameters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have list of items that I get from api call and I wanted to select the searched item from that list. For example I have got:

```
students: [{'fullName':'A'},{'fullName':'B'}] // this I get from api
```

Now I wanted to search names from that `students` and get the one which is selected.

Here is what I did:

```
<div class="text-center">
        <v-menu bottom offset-y>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-text-field
              append-icon="search"
              label="Filter By Student"
              single-line
              hide-details
              v-bind="attrs"
              v-on="on"
              />
          </template>
          <v-list style="max-height: 100px" v-model="searchStudent">
            <v-list-item
              v-for="item in filteredStudent"
              :key="item.fullName"
              v-bind="item"
            >
              <v-list-item-title  @click="filter_Students(item)">{{ item.fullName }}</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>
        </v-menu>
      </div>
export default {
    data () {
       students: [],
       searchStudent: '',
    },
    computed:{
       filteredResident:function(){
        var self=this;
        return this.students.filter(function(student){return students.fullName.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchStudent.toLowerCase())>=0;});
        }
    },
}
```

My problem is when I search for `fullName` from students list of object and select any one then I want to get the `fullName` of that selected student and bind with `searchStudent`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly. Try code below:

```js
return this.students
  .filter(({fullName}) => fullName.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchStudent.toLowerCase())
  .map(({fullName}) => fullName)
```